# This delete method allows me to delete multiple registers at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

tell me if this make sense:

```
public void Delete<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var model = _context.DbSet<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

    _context.DbSet<T>().Remove(model);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

From what I understand, the method enables deleting multiple records using predicate.
So, why is performed a query that returns only one record based on the predicate in this  method?

This method allows you to delete more than one record at the same time or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's returning a model by `FirstOrDefault`, which means 0 or 1.  It couldn't possibly delete more than one.

Perhaps a for-loop would be useful here.

```
for (var model in _context.DbSet<T>().Where(pedicate))
{
    _context.DbSet<T>().Remove(model);
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is a good step, because it ensures that you're not even calling the method if there are no results returned from the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

This method removes only first record, that matches the criteria. It doesn't make sense, especially when you really want to delete more that one record, because saving changes every time isn't a generic scenario.

Comment: Thank you, but, i'm scared about this, because this code can be found in a book of How to develop MVC Applications. Its a kind of official book. Thank you again.